Passing files to a controller
I have created a C# controller to receive files i pass from my client side. I get a error called "The files field is required" and cannot seem to fix it. Please note that I am new to C# and have only worked with JS.
Following is my controller
public class FileUploadController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("fileupload")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PackIt(List<IFormFile> files)
    {
        if (files == null || files.Count == 0)
        {
            return BadRequest("No files uploaded.");
        }

        return Ok(new { message = "Files received successfully." });
    }
}

And following is my client side code
async function sendLogicFiles(fileHandles: FileSystemFileHandle[]) {
  try {
    const formData = new FormData()
    fileHandles.forEach(async (file, index) => {
      const fileHandle = fileHandles[index]
      const _file = await fileHandle.getFile()
      formData.append(`files[${index}]`, _file)
    })
    const response = await fetch('fileupload', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
    })
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Network response was not ok ' + response.statusText)
    }
    const responseData = await response.json()
    console.log('Success:', responseData)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error)
  }
}

When I execute the code, I get the following error message for API response
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "errors": {
        "files": [
            "The files field is required."
        ]
    },
    "traceId": "00-2073e137b176760a1c75cd95b8a542dc-6f64030c375117eb-00"
}

How can I fix it? Or Am I in the right track to do this?

Tried adding the [FromForm] attribute. public async Task<IActionResult> PackIt([FromForm] List<IFormFile> files)

Hello have you tried the solution provided? Did you able to made any progress on this?

Try to use formData.append('files', _file) without index and add [FromForm] attribute.
[HttpPost]
[Route("fileupload")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PackIt([FromForm] List<IFormFile> files)
{
    if (files == null || files.Count == 0)
    {
        return BadRequest("No files uploaded.");
    }

    return Ok(new { message = "Files received successfully." });
}


@CraZyDroiD
If you want to send file to controller, you should create a model first.
public class FileModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [Display(Name = "image")]
    public IFormFile? image { get; set; }
}

And pass this model to your controller's action.
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,image")] FileModel model)
{
    T_File t_File = new T_File();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "wwwroot/Upload/Image"));
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }
        if (model.image != null)
        {
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, model.image.FileName), FileMode.Create))
            {
                await model.image.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }
        }
        t_File.staff_id = currentUser.Id;
        t_File.image = "/Upload/Image/" + model.image.FileName;

        _context.Add(t_File);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(model);
}

And please keep in mind to add  enctype="multipart/form-data" to form tag in the view.
Hope it can be helpful.

I have had a similar issue before and I resolved it by using "for...of" loop. From experience using the "foreach" loop in JavaScript does not wait for the 'await' before moving to the next iteration in an asynchronous code. You can read this https://www.squash.io/how-to-use-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop-in-javascript/ for more understanding.
In your sendLogicFiles function you  can replace the foreach with the code below
for (const fileHandle of fileHandles) {
  const _file = await fileHandle.getFile();
  formData.append('files', _file); 
}



I have created a C# controller to receive files i pass from my client
side. I get a error called "The files field is required" and cannot
seem to fix it. Please note that I am new to C# and have only worked
with JS.  How can I fix it? Or Am I in the right track to do this?

Well, based on your shared code snippet and description I have tried to investigate your snippet and I have following observations.
First of all, if you have take API controller, then using Attribute routing overriding your API controller so we can directly call that with the route name which is "fileupload"
Most importantly, the forEach within your JavaScript function does not properly handle asynchronous operations, leading to the fetch request being made before files are appended.
In order to fix that, use either a for...of loop or Promise.all to ensure all asynchronous operations complete before proceeding with the fetch request.
This ensures that the formData object is fully populated with the files before being sent to the server.
I have slightly refactored your code snippet. However, your controller code seems alright.
HTML:
<h1>Upload Files</h1>
<input type="file" id="fileInput" multiple>
<button onclick="uploadFiles()">Upload</button>

Javascript:
<script>
   
    async function uploadFiles() {
        alert("uploadFiles");
        const fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
        const fileHandles = [];

       
        for (let i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
            fileHandles.push(fileInput.files[i]);
        }

       
        await sendLogicFiles(fileHandles);
    }

    async function sendLogicFiles(fileHandles) {
        try {
            alert("sendLogicFiles");
            const formData = new FormData();
            for (let index = 0; index < fileHandles.length; index++) {
                const file = fileHandles[index];
                formData.append('files', file); 
            }
            console.log(formData);
            const response = await fetch('fileupload', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData,
            });

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok ' + response.statusText);
            }

            const responseData = await response.json();
            console.log('Success:', responseData);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        }
    }


    
</script>

Output:


Note: To summarize the issue it can be said, the problem in within your function lies in how it handles asynchronous operations within the forEach loop. The forEach method does not wait for the asynchronous await fileHandle.getFile() calls to complete before moving on to the next iteration or executing subsequent code. This means the fetch call may be made before all files are appended to the FormData object.
